# Merging with commit filtering?

Tags: git

I am regularly `git svn fetch`ing an active svn repo.  My intent is to maintain a read only mirror of the svn repo.

This svn repo has a couple of quirks. One of the directories is synced with a configuration directory that exists on several servers.

Instead of having distinct directories for each server the repo has a single directory that receives changes from all the servers. The file sets on each server have diverged significantly and basically each commit from each sync completely clobbers all the files in this single directory in the repo.

Luckily the commits messages are consistent, along the lines of, "Sync from server01", "Sync from server02", "Sync from server03", etc.

I would like to create several branches that separate these commits by their messages.

One branch would have only the "Sync" commits from from server01, another from server02, etc., and one last branch with everything except the "Sync..." commits.

I would like to be able to run a command at regular intervals to update these branches from subsequent `git svn fetch`es with the appropriate filtering for each branch.

I know a one time process could be accomplished with git-filter-branch.

I am not sure how to go about doing this in a streaming fashion for an active repo. Is there someway to do merge with filtering?

Or is there someway to `cherry-pick` all the commits that match a filter and then keep track of the last commit that got `cherry-pick`ed on the last run and continue from there?

For now I run `git svn fetch` at semi regular intervals.

I realize a better solution would be to just fix the borked Syncing process but that is currently beyond my pay grade.